# bash string manipulation fails without variable substitution

Tags: bash

I am on Ubuntu 16.04, bash version `4.3.48`

This way it works as expected:

```
string=cmake-3.16.4.tar.gz

echo ${string##*.}

gz
```

But this one fails:

```
echo ${cmake-3.16.4.tar.gz##*.}

3.16.4.tar.gz##*.
```

Comment: The syntax you are using is called *Parameter Expansion* not "string manipulation* - afaik it only works for parameters (i.e. variables) hence the `${...}`

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you for responding. Confused enough, do you have a simple approach to make it work? I mean the latter:

Comment: I'm not aware of any approach simpler that assigning the string to a variable first ex `x=cmake-3.16.4.tar.gz; echo ${x##*.}`